# How to disable cache-control for SAPUI5 Web IDE only?

Tags: sapui5, cache-control, sap-web-ide

I have set a cache-control in the neo-app.json and it's working fine on production but I want to disable on dev mode (SAP Web IDE) without opening Chrome DevTools and enabling "disable cache".

Can someone help ?
Thanks

Comment: Why? developer close the dev-tools never

Answer (score 0):

I guess the default run configuration itself has this in URL parameter `...&sap-ui-appCacheBuster=..%2F..%2F&sap-ui-xx-componentPreload=off&sap-ui-xx-viewCache=false#Shell-home`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand what your problem is, but we usually define separate launch-html pages, like one index.html for production and one index-webIDE.html for launching the app from the webIDE.

You can set up the configs like this:

Right-click the project -> Run -> Run Configurations

[image]

Then define your alternate starting html page for bootstrapping the app.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need the same thing with the neo-app.json file not the index.html. The cache is set in neo-app.